# Create a view in SQL based on 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL like below

```
Table 1: Order_Number , Cost
Table 2: ID_Number, Order_Number
```

I want to create a view in SQL to have a table like below:

```
ID_Number, Cost
```

What is the SQL code?

Comment: [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)). Where, specifically, are you stuck? The syntax for creating a view is *literally* just `CREATE VIEW {Your View's Name) AS {Single Statement that returns a result set with a SELECT};` What have *you* tried? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a query like below

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
Select ID_Number, Sum(Cost) as Cost
from Table1 t1
Join Table2 t2 on t1.Order_Number = t2.Order_Number
Group by ID_Number
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to create a view from two tables you use [JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Depending on your SQL dialect, creating a view syntax may vary a little bit, please refer to [creating views in SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp).

Comment: Your answer is no better than the question. Add tips and comments AS comments, not as an answer.